# Custom text/html in custom form module

Tags: 8, forms

I am following [this tutorial](http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-method-to-create-a-custom-form-in-drupal-8) and I've already created my custom form as Drupal 8 module.

I wonder, how to add custom text/html in form? I mean when somebody goes to the path pointed in `*.routing.yml`, I would like to display not only form fields, but also some intro html/text.

I know the form building is here:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

$form['name_surname'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Name and surname:'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
...
}
```

But I don't know what kind of entry (or `#type`) should I insert to get just an custom html/text block between fields or above them all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#field_prefix` `#field_suffix` and `#description` should do the trick. Here's more info about [FormElement](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21FormElement.php/class/FormElement/8.2.x). I believe you can also <s>set an element to type `markup` and then</s> use `#markup` to create an element that's just HTML ([see ya.teck's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219506/34502)).

Comment: #type markup has been removed https://www.drupal.org/node/2036237

Comment: To clarify to those who might not click ya.tect's link, `'#markup' => '<b>foo</b>'` still exists, you just dont need to specify, '`#type' => 'markup'` anymore.

Answer (score 24):

> What kind of entry (or #type) should I insert to get just an custom
>   html/text block between fields or above them all?

[Item](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Item.php/class/Item/8.2.x) element type provides a display-only form element with an optional title and description.

```
$form['help'] = [
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#title' => t('Block title'),
  '#markup' => t('Block content'),
];
```

You may also add arbitrary content to render arrays using the #markup render array key as follows.

```
$form['text']['#markup'] = t('Some text.');
```

Comment: This is handy, but beware: it won't work for unrecognized tags. Ex: `<foo></foo>`. I haven't figured out a way to do this yet.

Answer (score 2):

With Using `markup` you can add Html markups into your form.for an instance :

```
$form['help'] = [
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<a href="#">Find out more</a>',
    '#weight' => '3',

];
```

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2036237 - Not sure if you saw the comment earlier. Although the code will work as type markup will not have any effect.

Comment: Drupal just strips any HTML out of the '#markup' key, anyone know if there's a fix for this?